# Android. C2DM Received Authentication Challenge is Null Exception

Tags: android, authentication, android-c2dm

I am trying to use google c2dm to send push notifications on android device, but I have a little problem.
When I am trying to send a message I get this exception "java.IOException Received Authentication Challenge is Null" I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am using [Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html) to send c2dm.

```
public static String getToken(String email, String password)
        throws IOException {
    // Create the post data
    // Requires a field with the email and the password
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("Email=").append(email);
    builder.append("&Passwd=").append(password);
    builder.append("&accountType=GOOGLE");
    builder.append("&source=MyLittleExample");
    builder.append("&service=ac2dm");

    // Setup the Http Post
    byte[] data = builder.toString().getBytes();
    URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(data.length));

    // Issue the HTTP POST request
    OutputStream output = con.getOutputStream();
    output.write(data);
    output.close();

    // Read the response
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            con.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;
    String auth_key = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.startsWith("Auth=")) {
            auth_key = line.substring(5);
        }
    }

    // Finally get the authentication token
    // To something useful with it
    return auth_key;
}
```

Auth token is fine and return 200 code. But sending message is failure

```
public static int sendMessage(String auth_token, String registrationId,
        String message) throws IOException {

    StringBuilder postDataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    postDataBuilder.append(PARAM_REGISTRATION_ID).append("=")
            .append(registrationId);
    postDataBuilder.append("&").append(PARAM_COLLAPSE_KEY).append("=")
            .append("0");
    postDataBuilder.append("&").append("data.payload").append("=")
            .append(URLEncoder.encode(message, UTF8));

    byte[] postData = postDataBuilder.toString().getBytes(UTF8);

    // Hit the dm URL.

    URL url = new URL("https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");
    HttpsURLConnection
            .setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new CustomizedHostnameVerifier());
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
            Integer.toString(postData.length));
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth="
            + auth_token);

    OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
    out.write(postData);
    out.close();

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    return responseCode;
}
```

As I understand from other posts this error means 401 code, but I can't understand the reason of this, auth token is fine.

Comment: I just tried to send message with curl command and got 200 code, but push message not reached my device. I don't know why. After that I tried send push from my code again and got code 200 too.

Answer (score 0):

The URL used should be `https://android.clients.google.com/c2dm/send`, not `https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send`. Also, make sure that `PARAM_REGISTRATION_ID` is a string that equals **registration_id**, and not *registrationId* or something like that.